Prevent make from ever deleting anything
I have a Makefile set up as
config/%.toml:
    stuff

where I do
make config/x.toml

which runs a series of scripts based on the configuration file x.
Make will delete this file if I ^C or if the operation fails in certain cases, but not always.
I have tried adding
PRECIOUS: config/%.toml otherstuff/%

but this is sometimes ignored, and I have to recover the config file occasionally.
I want to prevent make from deleting anything, anywhere, at any time, globally, forever and always. How can I do this?

Using .PRECIOUS is the correct way to do this.  If you find that it doesn't always work, then that's a bug in GNU Make.  I am not familiar with any existing bug report to GNU Make that suggests .PRECIOUS does not work.  There are very few details provided here about exactly what "in certain cases" and "sometimes" means.  If you can provide a more concrete description that would be helpful.  I recommend asking on the help-make@gnu.org or bug-make@gnu.org mailing lists.

You say .PRECIOUS but I used PRECIOUS. Is this maybe the reason? The docs also say .PRECIOUS.

Definitely PRECIOUS means nothing to make and will have no impact.  You need to use .PRECIOUS.  Sorry I didn't notice this; I just assumed you used .PRECIOUS.

I feel dumb now. I could close, or have you answer it. Maybe someone else will have the same problem.

Use .PRECIOUS: ... not PRECIOUS: ...
As @MadScientist points out, I was writing PRECIOUS: ... instead of .PRECIOUS: ...
